# File Transport between Server/Client

Tags: java, thrift

What kind of Service should I define for ".thrift"-file to use it later for my Program?

This File Transport should be between the Client and the Server and it should be "partly".

StreamFileService.thrift:

```
struct FileChunk {
1: binary data
2: i64 remaining
}

service StreamFileService {    
FileChunk getBytes(1:string fileName, 2: i64 offset, 3: i32 size);    
}
```

StreamFileClient.java:

```
public class StreamFileClient {
private int fileChunkSize = 16;
private String filePath;

public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

private void invoke() {

    try {

        TTransport theClientTransport = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket(
                "127.0.0.1", 7911));
        TProtocol theProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(theClientTransport);
        StreamFileService.Client theClient = new StreamFileService.Client(
                theProtocol);
        theClientTransport.open();

        filePath = "/home/output/output.pdf";
        File theFile2 = new File(filePath);
        theFile2.createNewFile();
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(theFile2);
        long currentPosition = 0;

        FileChannel theFileChannel = stream.getChannel();
        boolean again = true;

        do {
            FileChunk chunk2 = theClient.getBytes(filePath,
                    currentPosition, fileChunkSize);
            currentPosition += fileChunkSize;

            theFileChannel.write(chunk2.data);

            if (chunk2.remaining == 0)
                again = false;

        } while (again);
        stream.close();

    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamFileClient theClient = new StreamFileClient();

    theClient.invoke();

}
```

}

StreamFileServer.java:

```
public class StreamFileServer {

private void start() {
    try {

        TNonblockingServerTransport theServerSocket = new TNonblockingServerSocket(
                7911);
        StreamFileService.Processor theProcessor = new StreamFileService.Processor(
                new StreamFileServiceImpl());
        TServer theServer = new TNonblockingServer(
                new TNonblockingServer.Args(theServerSocket)
                        .processor(theProcessor));
        System.out.println("Server starting on port 7911...");

        theServer.serve();

    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StreamFileServer theFileServer = new StreamFileServer();
    theFileServer.start();
}
```

}

StreamFileServiceImpl:

```
  public class StreamFileServiceImpl implements StreamFileService.Iface {

public FileChunk getBytes(String filePath, long offset, int size)
        throws TException {

    File theFile = new File("/home/input/kl_12.pdf");
    FileChunk chunk = new FileChunk();

    try {

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(theFile);

        MappedByteBuffer buffer = stream.getChannel().map(
                FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, offset, size);
        chunk.data = buffer;
        chunk.remaining = stream.getChannel().size() - offset - size;
        stream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return chunk;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you try to improve your question? And what does "partly" mean? And maybe describe what you already tried? In it's current format the question is quite likely to be closed, not answered.

Comment: I am trying to implement Server->Client - Filetransfer with Thrift. "Partly" means not all the length of the file once to transfer but twice or thrice to transfer.

Comment: This is how my Service looks like (StreamFileService.thrift):  typedef binary binar

service StreamFileService {

 binar getBytes(1:string fileName);
 
}

Comment: Please don't put code into comments. You can see for yourself that it's totally illegible. Edit it into your question. There's not enough information here yet to answer your question.

Comment: May I ask if the service is publicly visible over e.g. the internet? In that case, security-wise it is probably a bad idea to allow for arbitrary file paths. In a controlled environment, however, this may or may not be fine. Depends on the environment setup.

Comment: No, it is not publicly visible. Thanks a lot! It helped.

Comment: How will the Client side looks like with this "partly" transfer of the file?

Comment: Depends. You iterate as long as you get data from the server any write chunk after chunk into the output stream. Or, if you want to decouple it somewhat more and read only one chunk at a time, with potentially large pauses in between, you reopen the file, move to its end and get the current length, retrieve the next chunk from the server and write it into the output file.

Comment: Hi Jens. Would you please have a look in the new maded classes by me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks not so bad to me (not tested) and there is not much to change.

How about

```
typedef binary binar
service StreamFileService {    
   binar getBytes(1:string fileName, 2: i64 offset, 3: i32 size);    
   i64 getSize(1:string fileName)
}
```

I would also return a struct holding the bytes, but that's more or less my personal opinion.

```
struct FileChunk {
  1: binary data
  2: i64 remaining
}

service StreamFileService {    
   FileChunk getBytes(1:string fileName, 2: i64 offset, 3: i32 size);    
}
```

The `FileChunk` struct can be easily extended, if such becomes necessary, e.g. in order to return additional metadata, like total size (especially if the size grows/shrinks over time), remaining bytes, indications about the data format, or the like. You don't have to do that, as you can easily extend the interface if such becomes necessary later. Matter of taste.