# How to upload a file (image, zip ..) with Apache Thrift?

Tags: apache, file, upload, thrift, photos

i am developing a file upload system. I am going to use apache Thrift. Can you suggest me some ideas that can be used as a server apache upload files.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Thrift large file in messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188775/thrift-large-file-in-messages). Just follow the advice outlined over there.

Comment: Thanks, Should use Thift server to upload or use a different upload?

Comment: If you plan to use Thrift RPC then you have to do it on both ends. The Thrift RPC stack is quite specific. But that's the whole point of Thrift: [To connect platforms and languages in a quick, easy, strongly typed and comfortable manner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706).

Comment: Do you have any solution alternative to Thrift? or an open-source server used to upload files?

Comment: The title of the question is "*How to upload a file (image, zip ..) with Apache Thrift?*". Now you ask "*Do you have any solution alternative to Thrift*" followed by "*or an open-source server used to upload files?*" -  Well, if that is not confusing, I don't know what is. [Maybe you should think again what you want to achieve at all, and then rewrite the whole question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).